# If statement with 3 conditions (triangleExists)

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

Check if TriangleExists: it is when every 1 of its side is smaller than the sum of the 2 others.

I tried a lot of options:

```
float a=3, b=15, c=7; //its still taking 'y'
bool triangleExists(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if ((a < (b + c)) || (b < (a + b)) || (c < (a + b)))
    {
        std::cout << "y" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }else 
        std::cout << "n" << std::endl;;
        return false;
}
```

Options I tried (they were also tried with && marks):

1. `if ((a < (b + c)) || (b < (a + b)) || (c < (a + b)))`
2. `if ( a < (b + c) || b < (a + b) || c < (a + b))`
3. `if ((a < (b + c))==true || (b < (a + b))==true || (c < (a + b))==true)`
4. `if (a < b + c || b < a + b || (c < a + b)`

I'm probably missing something simple.  I'll be glad if you can help.

Comment: What's the question and the problem? Also, provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"when every 1 of its side is smaller than the sum of the 2 others"*: you must use the `&&` (logical AND) operator, not `||` (logical OR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your middle condition, you have b < (a + b), when it should be b < (a + c)

Comment: hahahahahahahhahahahahahah 30 minutes of thinking, Thanks. I really was to tired last night.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the typo that @Zackary Murphy already pointed out, you have a more fundamental problem with your logic.

In particular, your function should return `true` only if *all three* conditions are passed. With the middle term corrected to `b < (a + c)`, it *still* returns `true` (and prints `y`) even though the numbers you've specified can't form a triangle.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

bool triangleExists(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if ((a < (b + c)) || (b < (a + c)) || (c < (a + b)))
    {
        std::cout << "y" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "n" << std::endl;;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    float a = 3, b = 4, c = 500; //its still taking 'y'

    triangleExists(a, b, c);
}
```

... prints `y`, even though sides of `3`, `4` and `500` can't form a triangle.

To get correct behavior, you can change from using `||` to `&&` (i.e., from `or` to `and`). Alternatively, you can invert the test and invert the results--that is, if a > (b + c) || b > (a + c) || c > (a + b), then return false. Only otherwise, return true.

Comment: ye i did it already this way yesterday. && was my first catch but when i was tried it just catch every of solve that can help. anyway thanks for reply.